# How to make a while loop for a multiplication table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to create a multiplication chart with a while loop for an assignment but I am having a hard time getting the expected output.

I have tried everything I can think of. I am new to the coding world.

```
#While loop
print('While Loop')
print()
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1
while x <= 12:
     print(x ,end='\t')
     x += 1

while y <= 12:
     print('\n')
     print(y,'\t')
     y += 1 
     while z <= 12:
          print(x*z ,end='\t')
          z += 1
     z = 0
     x = 1
```

I expect the output to be
[image: correctchart]

but I get

[image: incorrectchart].

Comment: shouldn't you use `y*z` instead of `x*z`?

Comment: It's a 2D chart so you should only need `x` and `y`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `x` is for the heading line, `y` and `z` are for the chart.

Comment: You need to print `X\t` before the first loop, to create the cross in the corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** you use `x*z` when you calculate the product, but you use `y` as a "row counter" and `z` as a "column counter" so it should be `y*z`. Furthermore you should increment the `y` *after* the inner `while` loop.

Since you use `y` as the "row counter" and `z` as the "column counter", you should print `y * z` as the answer of that specific multiplication. Furthermore you increment `y` too soon: you should increment it after the `while` loop, and reset `z` to 1, like:

```
print('While Loop')
print('x', end='\t')  # print a cross

x = 1
while x <= 12:
     print(x ,end='\t')
     x += 1

y = 1
while y <= 12:
     print('')
     print(y,end='\t')
     z = 1  # reset to 1
     while z <= 12:
          print(y*z ,end='\t')  # use y * z
          z += 1
     y += 1  # incerement after while loop
print()
```

## Using `for` loops

There are also some minor formatting issues. For example you should first `print('X', end='\t')` since otherwise the columns do not match correctly.

That being said, you make things way harder than these should be. You can make use of a `for` loop instead, like:

```
print('x', end='\t')
print('\t'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 13)))

for r in range(1, 13):
    print(r, end='\t')
    print('\t'.join(str(r*c) for c in range(1, 13)))
```

or in a function:

```
def mulgrid(n):
    print('x', end='\t')
    print('\t'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)))
    for r in range(1, n+1):
        print(r, end='\t')
        print('\t'.join(str(r*c) for c in range(1, n+1)))
```

For example:

```
>>> mulgrid(1)
x   1
1   1
>>> mulgrid(2)
x   1   2
1   1   2
2   2   4
>>> mulgrid(5)
x   1   2   3   4   5
1   1   2   3   4   5
2   2   4   6   8   10
3   3   6   9   12  15
4   4   8   12  16  20
5   5   10  15  20  25
>>> mulgrid(7)
x   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2   2   4   6   8   10  12  14
3   3   6   9   12  15  18  21
4   4   8   12  16  20  24  28
5   5   10  15  20  25  30  35
6   6   12  18  24  30  36  42
7   7   14  21  28  35  42  49
```

Comment: I have to create two charts with the for and while loop. I have already done the for loop so I am just stuck on the while loop. And switching it to y*z did help but the chart order is still wacky.

Comment: @Megan: as said, you should multiply `y*z`, and increment `y` *after* the inner `while` loop.

Comment: It still does not work well. `1` (alone) on the third line and `1 2 3...` on the next one, etc

Comment: Also, I would replace `print('\n')` with `print('')` for a more compact formatting